# Change child element Fill on property change ToggleButton.IsChecked

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ToggleButton, with a Canvas inside it, holding an Ellipse.

```
              <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsUpgradeOpen, Mode=OneWayToSource}"  
    x:Name="upgradeButton"  
        Click="upgradeButton_Click" Background="Transparent">
               ....
               ....
               <Canvas Name="svg4203pro" Width="40" Height="40">
                 ....
                 <Ellipse xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Name="patph41591" Fill="#FF494949">
```

When the ToggleButton IsChecked, I would like to change the colour of the Ellipse.

I can't figure out a way to do it that works.

**Attempt 1.**

```
<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsUpgradeOpen, Mode=OneWayToSource}"  
        x:Name="upgradeButton"  
            Click="upgradeButton_Click" Background="Transparent">
               <ToggleButton.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true" >
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="patph41591" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).Color">
                                                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Red"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ToggleButton.Style>
```

This gives me the error `TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter.`, which I wasn't expecting because I *was* able to do something similar for a mouse over effect (that I can get the mouse over effect to work so easily and this not is baffling to me).

This works for the mouse over

```
<ToggleButton.Triggers>

                    <EventTrigger  RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">

                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="patph41591" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).Color">
                                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="#6dbd63"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
```

**Attempt 2.**

Try and change the style from the Ellipse itself, rather than the parent ToggleButton

```
 <Ellipse xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="1012.3" Width="40" Height="40" Name="patph41591" 
                                 Fill="#FF494949" StrokeThickness="7.80000019" StrokeMiterLimit="4" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Square" 
                                 StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Opacity="1">
                            <Ellipse.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=IsUpgradeOpen}"
                                    Value="True">
                                            <!--RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}-->
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Ellipse.Style>
                        </Ellipse>
```

This uses the DataContext property IsUpgradeOpen, which is bound to ToggleButton.IsClicked, but it just does nothing.  No binding errors, nothing.

There are no other styles assigned to ToggleButton.

Comment: Your second attempt should work (i guess, assuming the binding resolves successfully) if you add a property setter with the initial value for Fill to the style (don't use Fill on the Ellipse itself).

Comment: @elgonzo You're right!  Thanks.  If you write it up I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: I flagged your question as a duplicate (with the duplicate quesion having the answer that applies to your case here).